# Plugin code only generating HTML5

Tags: html, iframe, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to add a Like Box to my website (I have done several before) and I use iFrame code.  When I fill in the info and click Get Code it shows the normal code options... HTML5 etc.  However, when I click on the other code options nothing happens.  It just stays on HTML5.  I have tried several different browsers, reset my settings and tried again.  Still doing the same thing... any help?

Comment: I am trying to get the iFrame Like Box code - so I don't have the code to begin with.  After I click on the Get Code button, the window pops up but when I click on iFrame nothing happens.